# What is the correct formula for "if-function" to replace text in separate column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I believe I should be using `if` function. I'm trying to say
If "Unpaid" is changed to "Paid" then the Amount would change to "0"

I had `=IF(E4="Paid",C4,"$0")` but it's only changing column `f` and I want column `c` to have the `0`

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TSQCl6n1wnxN_uiZEzRoITEvpB29UErrcbMxnkb6SBE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am building a debt tracker currently I have listed all the unpaid debts in column C and labeled them “Unpaid” in column E. However if I type  “paid” in column E I want what ever is in the row of column C to change to 0 or $0

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in F column and use in F3:

```
=INDEX(IF(A3:A="",,IF(E3:E="Paid", C3:C, 0)))
```

transcript: if A column is empty do nothing. if e column equals Paid grab C column otherwise output 0

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0, That's not quite what I'm looking for but it is close. I am building a debt tracker currently I have listed all the unpaid debts in column C and labeled them “Unpaid” in column E. However if I type “paid” in column E I want what ever is in the row of column C to change to 0 or $

Comment: @Autumn.Shantae that wont be possible without script